# 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.deviceLocale')

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I am trying to validate a text field on click of Submit button. But I always get the error -

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.deviceLocale') on my emulator.

(I am using an Android emulator).

However I am nowhere using 'deviceLocale' in my code. I am not aware if it is required for anything I have in my code.

This is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import ValidationComponent from 'react-native-form-validator';

export default class App extends ValidationComponent {
  
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      name: "abc"
    }
  }

  _onPressButton() {
    this.validate({
      name: {minlength: 3, maxlength: 7, required: true},
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <View>

        <TextInput 
          ref = "name"
          onChangeText = {(name) => this.setState({name})}
          value = {this.state.name}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this._onPressButton}>
          <Text>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Error snap:

[image]

Comment: Please add your validate method's code and also, when is this error exactly occuring? on tapping of the button ?

Comment: @SurajMalviya, what do you mean by validate method's code? I am asking because I am new to this. I am validating my only text field in _onPressButton(). The error is not occuring on press of button. It occurs before even loading the initial page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error even before loading of the component then, do bind your `_onPressButton` correctly, then atleast your component will get mounted properly, then then your upcoming errors will follow like the use of `this.validate` is somewhat ambiguous to me as I cannot see `validate` function in the component.

To bind your `_onPressed`, declare it like below:

```
_onPressButton = () => {
  this.validate({
    name: {minlength: 3, maxlength: 7, required: true},
  });
}
```

The error is causing as `_onPressed` is getting called as soon as your component is getting mounted. Let me know in comments if this helps you getting ahead with your component mounting atleast.

**Edited:**
Also, your constructor doesn't provide props to the super constructor,

Declare it like below:

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     name: "abc"
   }
 }
```